# Bulbs python Connection to a remote TitanDB + Rexster

Tags: python, cassandra, titan, bulbs, rexster

I'm using TitanGraphDB + Cassandra. I'm starting Titan as follows

```
cd titan-cassandra-0.3.1
bin/titan.sh config/titan-server-rexster.xml config/titan-server-cassandra.properties
```

I have a Rexster shell that I can use to communicate to Titan + Cassandra above.

```
cd rexster-console-2.3.0
bin/rexster-console.sh
```

I'm attempting to model a network topology using Titan Graph DB. I want to program the Titan Graph DB from my python program. I'm using `python bulbs` package for that.My code to create the graph is as follows.

```
from bulbs.titan import Graph 
self.g = Graph()
```

Now I have rexster-console and Titan running on machine with IP Address `192.168.65.93`.If my python application is runnnig on the same machine I use `self.g = Graph()`.

What if I want to connect to the `Titan AND Rexster` running on machine with IP `192.168.65.93` from python application on `192.168.65.94`

How do I do that? Can I pass some parameter (e.g a config file to Graph())? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the Titan graph URI in the Bulbs `Config` object:

```
>>> from bulbs.titan import Graph, Config
>>> config = Config('http://192.168.65.93:8182/graphs/graph')
>>> g = Graph(config)
```

See Bulbs `Config`...

- http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/config/
- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/config.py

And Bulbs `Graph` (note Titan's `Graph` class is a subclass of Rexster's `Graph` class)...

- http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/rexster/graph/
- https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/titan/graph.py

And I encourage you to read through the Bulbs Quickstart and other docs because many of these questions are answered in there...

- http://bulbflow.com/docs/
- http://bulbflow.com/quickstart/

The Quickstart uses `bulbs.neo4jserver` as an example, but since the Bulbs API is consistent regardless of the backend server you are using, the Quickstart examples are also relevant to Titan Server and Rexster.

To adapt the Bulbs Quickstart for Titan or Rexster, simply change the `Graph` import from...

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
```

...to...

```
>>> from bulbs.titan import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
```

...or...

```
>>> from bulbs.rexster import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
```

Comment: What is the difference between using `from bulbs.titan import Graph` and `from bulbs.rexster import Graph`? Do both of them use Rexster's REST API to communicate with the Titan database? If yes, can you please point out the advantage of one over the other?